# Can we build a nondeterministic decider PDA using two PDAs accepting a language and its complement?

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

When talking about turing machines, it can be easily shown that starting from two machines accepting $L$ and its complement $L^c$, one can build a machine which can fully decide if a word is inside $L$ or not.

But what about PDAs? starting from two different PDAs, one accepting $L$ and one accepting $L^c$ can we build another PDA, which accepts $L$, and only crashes or halts in non-final states (rejects) when $w\notin L$?

Comment: PDAs always halt, so you only need the first one.

Comment: @LukeMathieson PDAs can stuck in infinite loops because of their $\epsilon$-transitions!

Comment: @ali-s, good point, but you can always convert a PDA to an equivalent PDA that halts on all inputs.

Comment: @LukeMathieson that's only about DPDAs, it's not as easy for Nondet. PDA. In fact if I'm not mistaken, halting in PDAs is either open problem, or proven to be as hard as in turing machines.

Comment: @ali-s, that's a different question though (whether a given PDA halts or not given the input), we can just take any PDA, convert it to a CFG, then back to a PDA. The PDA at the end provably halts (regardless of whether the original did or not).

Comment: @Ali.S It's not always useful to look at automata as algorithms, in particular when non-determinism enter the picture.

Comment: @LukeMathieson There is a possibility that other people may come up with that kind of question. Hence I would recommend keeping it. However, it would be nice that the system stops bugging us with it. My suggestion is that you turn your comments into an answer, so that the OP can accept it, and we do not have to deal with it any longer.

Comment: @babou done and done.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to do so. Although a given PDA may have $\varepsilon$ loops that can induce infinite computation, we can sidestep this by converting the PDA to a CFG, then back to a PDA (using the standard methods). The second PDA is guaranteed to halt on all inputs (this is not too hard to see if you know the conversion method - essentially you guarantee that either a non-terminal from the CFG is added to the stack, or a terminal is read from the input at each broad step and the nondeterminism takes care of the rest, or equivalently, CFGs can always be parsed).

So then we can take the PDA for $L$, apply this transition, and we get a machine that always halts, and only halts in an accept state if the input is in $L$.

Comment: There is a little problem with your method, you can't compute the product of two PDAs. If we could, we could also compute intersection of two CFGs, but there are few easy example, showing that intersection of two CFGs might not be a CFL at all (though it's always CSL). Take $a^nb^nc^*$ and $a^*b^nc^n$ for example. Their intersection is $a^nb^nc^n$ which we know is not CFL using pumping lemma.

Comment: @Ali.S, you are correct, I got too fancy. I've gone back to the simpler version from the comments.

Comment: Essentially, it seems that one does not need two PDA's, if a non-deterministic acceptor is OK. Which means that this works even when the complement is not CF. The troubling point is that non-determinism does not behave symmetrically for acceptace and rejection. What remains important is the remark that a NPDA can always be turned into one that never loops for ever.

Answer (score -1):

DPDA class is close under complement.

if you have a PDA for $L$ and an other one for $L^c$ then $L \in \{ L\subset \Sigma | \quad \exists DPDA\quad  \text{ such that} L=L(DPDA)\} $ so you can make a non-deterministic decider for L.

---

After Edit:

@Ali.S:
It seems you are right. Although it’s difficult for me to make a PDA for $L- WW^R$.

But again I think it’s possible to have non-deterministic decider!

Let $M_1$ be a non-deterministic acceptor for $L$ and $M_2$ be a nondeterministic acceptor for $L^c$.
$\forall w \in L^c$ , $M_2$’s answer is “Yes” and it means $\forall w \notin L$ , $ M_2$ will halt.
We can construct a non-deterministic decider as follows:

Put a new initial state and add two lambda transition from it to $ M_1$ and $ M_2$ initial states. 
Wherever in $M_2$ we have “Yes” we change it to “No” and if it has “No” answer we stuck in loop.
Wherever in $M_1$ we have “yes” it is what we wanted and if it has “No” answer we stuck in a loop.

By this way if $w \in L$ if PDA decide to goes $M_1$ initial state and continue it will get answer "Yes" and halts. if it chooses to start by $M_2$ initial state and continues it won't get answer "No". if $w \notin L$ and PDA choose to goes in $M_1$ if will get stuck in loop and if it goes in $M_2$ it will get answer "No" and halt.

Comment: $ww^R$ has a PDA, it's complement also is CFG and has a PDA. but neither of those has DPDA.